# Estimating inner product over $[r]^d$

Tags: reference-request, communication-complexity

Alice has a vector $x \in [r]^d$ and Bob has $y \in [r]^d$, where $[r] \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \{0,1,\dots,r\}$. Alice send a message $M(x)$ to Bob and Bob wants to estimate the inner product $\left<x,y\right>$ with multiplicative error $\epsilon$ with probability $1 - \delta$.

My question is. Is there any known lower bound on $|M(x)|$? My intuition tells me that Alice pretty much has to estimate each coordinate of $x$ up to $\epsilon$ precision since Bob can have an input that zeros out all but one of the entry. Does that give you something like $\Omega(d \log 1/\epsilon)$?

Comment: What is $[r]$?  Do you mean, e.g., $[0,r]$?

Comment: I should have clarified, it means integers from 0 to r.

Comment: Then surely your bound should depend on $r$?  E.g., even with $\epsilon=d=1$ and $\delta=1/2$, Bob needs to know something about the magnitude of $x_1$?

Comment: Then maybe it should be something like $d(\log \log r + \log 1/\epsilon)$? This is the number of bits you need to if we round $x_i$ to the nearest exponent of $1+\epsilon$.

Comment: I agree that Alice can do it deterministically with that many bits, and can't do better deterministically.   If the inner product is at least some $T$, it would be enough for Alice to choose some $k=O(\log(1/\delta) d r^2/(T \epsilon^2))$ indices $i\in[d]$ at random, and just send the approximate $x_i$ for each of those.  (Bob would compute the corresponding random sample.) This would be better when $\log(1/\delta) r^2 \ll \epsilon^2 T$.

Comment: FWIW the case $r=1$ and $y$ restricted to vectors with a single non-zero coordinate is similar to the problem that Bloom filters solve (compress a bit vector $x$ into a small bit string $M(x)$ so that, using only $M(x)$, one can confidently test, for a given $i$, whether $x_i=1$).  If $x$ has, say, $d/2$ bits set, I think such a Bloom filter requires $\Omega(d)$ bits.  On the other hand Bloom filters don't have false negatives.

Comment: may be relevant: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/one-way-randomized-communication-complexity-of-approximate-hamming-distance

Comment: So it is not necessary for Alice to approximate every $x_i$, or rather it depends on a lower bound on the inner product? I think the case when $r = 1$ is the problem of estimating set intersection and there is an optimal $\Omega(d/(T\epsilon^2))$ lower bound according to [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/psw14.pdf). I am interested in how it extends to general $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the indexing problem Alice has a vector $x \in \{0,1\}^d$ and Bob has a number $i$, and Bob wants to learn $x_i$. The randomized one-way communication complexity of this problem is $\Omega(d)$ (see Section 3 of [this paper](https://www.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v004a006/v004a006.pdf)), and it can be solved by approximating $x_i = \langle x, e_i\rangle$ up to any multiplicative factor where $e_i$ is the vector with $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate and $0$'s everywhere else. So your problem has $\Theta(d)$ randomized one-way communication complexity for $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks! I think [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/psw14.pdf) also contain a bound $\Omega(n/(T\epsilon^2))$ that also show dependence on $\epsilon$. I wonder whether it makes sense or not to ask how the bound generalizes to general $r$.